# Using SendMessage() to write to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, process, real-time, sendmessage

I made before a program where I could open a process of the notepad and while it's **opened**, be able to write in it from the C# program console. Now I'm trying to do the same but with the excel, I can run the process, I can open it and I can kill it. But when I try to write in it with the SendMessage() method, nothing happens, is there a way I can do this? Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Here's what I tried so far

Declarations

```
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    //include SendMessage
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    extern static int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const uint WM_PASTE = 0x302;
    const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;
    const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    const int EM_SETSEL = 0x00B1;
    const int EM_REPLACESEL = 0x00C2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Abre o programa
        Process prcss = new Process();
        prcss.StartInfo.FileName = "excel.exe";
        prcss.Start();
        string aux = prcss.StartInfo.FileName;

        //Verifica se o processo está a correr
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Code to write in it with the SendMessage().

```
case "2":

                while (true)
                {

                    //Testar com o SendMessage
                    Console.WriteLine("\nTexto: \n");
                    string texto = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (aux.Length == 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (prcss != null)
                    {
                        IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(prcss.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "edit", null);
                        int length = SendMessageGetTextLength(notepadTextbox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

                        if (!notepadTextbox.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                        {
                            //sending the message to the textbox
                            SendMessage(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, texto);
                            SendMessage(notepadTextbox, EM_SETSEL, length, length);
                            SendMessage(notepadTextbox, EM_REPLACESEL, 1, texto + "\n");

                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Sair? (S)im / (N)ão");
                    sair = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (sair == "s" || sair == "S")
                    {
                        IntPtr k = prcss.MainWindowHandle;
                        SetForegroundWindow(k);
                        prcss.Kill();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why do that at all? Why not use Excel Interop, which was built for exactly this reason?

Comment: The messages you send are text editing messages. Excel isn't an editor though. You can't just start typing, you have to select a cell first, enter edit mode and start editing its contents. The cell goes into edit mode automatically when you start typing or when you press F2.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you point me to an example on how to do it with the interop?

Comment: That's thoroughly documented in learn.microsoft.com, courses, tutorials and books. Just google for `Excel Interop`. Check for example [How to: Access Office Interop Objects by Using Visual C# Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects)

Comment: But how can I send strings to and excel cell without closing anything? Just like what happens with notepad. Because for that, I need processes

Comment: Did you read the link to the docs? Did you *try* it? Excel isn't Notepad or any kind of text editor. You don't need to start the process yourself either, that's what `new Excel.Application();` does. Whey you try to access an application through COM, Windows itself starts the "server" application.